# SQL Select One to Many

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I can't think any term on this matter instead I give to you the tables that I want to show.

```
Table 1
ID | Product | Description
1  | Dell    | Dell Laptop

Table 2
ID | ProductID | Attribute | Description
1  | 1         | Processor | i7
2  | 1         | USB 3.0   | USB 3.0 Descript
```

Using join I can show the result like this:

```
Product | Attribute | Description
Dell    | Processor | i7
Dell    | USB 3.0   | USB 3.0 Descript
```

What I want to show is something like this.

```
Product | Attribute | Description
Dell    | Processor | i7
        | USB 3.0   | USB 3.0 Descript
```

The product name only shows once if the ProductID of table 2 is the same to previous ProductID of previous row. How I can do this using only SQL?

Comment: You should do this in your application.  Although possible in SQL, it is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing this on my application and its working good, but because of curiosity I want to know if this is possbile in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @GordonLinoff stated above, this should be done on the application side rather than using SQL. Here is how you can do this in MySQL:

```
SET @row_number := 0 ;
SET @productnames:='';

SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN num = 1
          THEN t.Product
    ELSE '' 
    END Product,
    t.Attribute,
    t.Description
FROM
(SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE WHEN @productnames=t1.product 
                       THEN @row_number+1 
                     ELSE 1 END AS num,
    @productnames:=t1.product AS product,
    t2.Attribute,
    t2.Description
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ProductID
) t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c299/16/2)

The trick here is to assign a fake row_number and then only populate the `Product` column when the row_number =  1 using a `case when` statement. Hope this helps!

Comment: it wont work if I have another product and components associated to that product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it work as per your requirement:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY tab2.ProductID ORDER BY ProductID
                ) > 1
            THEN ''
        ELSE tab1.Product
        END Product
    ,tab2.Attribute
    ,tab2.[Description]
FROM (
    SELECT 1 ID
        ,'Dell' Product
        ,'Dell Laptop' [Description]
    ) tab1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 ID
        ,1 ProductID
        ,'Processor' Attribute
        ,'i7' [Description]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2
        ,1
        ,'USB 3.0'
        ,'USB 3.0 Descript'
    ) tab2 ON tab1.ID = tab2.ProductID
```